# Combining categories of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vertex

I am new to R and
I have the following dataframe below with `living_arrangements` vertex on the y axis and `loneliness_level` vertex on the x axis.
[image]

What would be the best way if I wanted to to combine `Alternate between parents and partner` and `College or student accomodation` into its own unique category called `other` so I have my dataframe like the one below instead?

```
                                    loneliness_level
living_arrangements       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Alone                     1 1 0 2 0 1 1 3 1 4
Other                     1 2 5 2 2 1 2 3 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to get the sum, use `rowsum`

```
out <- rowsum(m1, group = c(1, 2, 2))
row.names(out) <- c("Alone", "Other")
names(dimnames(out)) <- names(dimnames(m1))
```

-output

```
> out
                   loneliness_level
living_arrangements 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
              Alone 1 1 0 2 0 1 1 3 1  4
              Other 1 2 5 2 2 1 2 3 1  0
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    living_arrangements = c("Alone", "Alternate between parents and partner", 
    "College or student accomodation"), loneliness_level = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")))
```